# MacBook Pro won't boot after remove boot partition

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

I want to install W10 on my macBook Pro, after searching about a solution all ideas seems dont work with me.

Now, I Follow instruction for BootCamp, i restart my MBP, it gave an error message: No bootable disk found, please insert ...

I went with restarting and option solution I selected the EFI boot going to W10 and when I want install it on BOOTCAMP partition it wont.

when I want to return to the begening, i deleted the BootCamp partition and another partition wich has 600 Mo about, but when i want restarting with my Mac Ox it wont boot, i clicked on option, and here no Machintosh partition is here, I think that I deleted the boot partition.

please can somone give me a solution to reinstall it without formating my MAC

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to net-boot by holding command-option-R at startup (it has to be online of course). This will give you the option to reinstall Mac OS X, and you won't have to erase your disk to do it unless the disk is already damaged/corrupted.

Comment: Hy again SegNerd i tried your idea but when i want to select my disk and install it again it show me this message: This disk cannot be configured to boot your computer

Comment: Have you tried running Disk Utility on it? How is the disk formatted?